# Run length encoding using prolog

Tags: prolog, run-length-encoding

I am starting to learn Prolog by solving different example. I am doing run length encoding on text data using Prolog, which should produce a character followed by the number of times it occurs in sequence. I want the answer to be in the format below. This is popular question as it is on 99 prolog website, but i couldn't find a proper answer elsewhere. Please check the code and see if you can help me find the fix.

answer format; [('a',3),('b',2),('c',1),('a',2)]

```
myencode([],[]).
myencode([First|Rest], Encoded) :- run(Rest,First,1,Encoded).

run([], Last,N,[Last,N]).
run([H|T], Prev, N, Encoded) :-
    dif(N, Prev),
    Encoded=[Prev, N|Rest],
    run(T,H,1,Rest);
    succ(N,N1),
    run(T,H,N1,Encoded).
```

Comment: You want to compare H and Prev, not N and Prev, on the first line of last clause...

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please edit the question with any changes you have made. Also please add an example query, what you expect the query to do, and how it behaves instead. Also, you should be very careful about using `;`. It is almost always much better to use separate clauses for disjunction. The `;` is very subtle and easy to miss.